Proof that any algebraically closed field is homogeneous.
Hi guys I'm currently try to solve one of the exercises in Marker's "Model Theory: An Introduction" and I'm kinda stuck. The exercise asks to prove that any algebraically closed field is homogeneous. In this context an $L$-structure $\underline{M}$ is said to be homogeneous if for every subset $A\subset M$ with $|A|<|M|$, for each partial elementary embedding $h:A\to M$ and for each $b\in M\setminus A$ there exists a partial elementary embedding $h'$ extending $h$ such that $b$ lies in the domain of $h'$.
So the setting of the proof is the following: $\underline F\models ACF$, $A\subset F$ with $|A|<|F|$, $h:A\to F$ is a partial elementary embedding and $b\in F\setminus A$.
What I was trying to do was to prove that $tp^{\underline{F}}(b/A)=tp^{\underline{F}}(d/h(A))$ for some $d\in F$, this way I can extend $h$ to $h'=h\cup \{(b,d)\}$ thus concluding the proof.
I think I can distinguish two cases: the first is when there exists some polynomial $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\dots +a_nx^n$ such that $\underline{F}\models f(b)=0$, the other case is when such polynomial doesn't exists.
Case 1: in such case the type $tp^{\underline{F}}(b/A)$ is clearly isolated (because it is algebraic), so there exists some $\phi(x,\overline{a})$ isolating the type (here $\overline{a}\in A^m$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$). Moreover knowing that $f(b)=a_0+a_1b+\dots +a_nb^n=0$ using the partial elementary embedding $h$ I can prove that there exists some $d\in F$ such that $h(a_0)+h(a_1)d+\dots+h(a_n)d^n=0$. I also know that $ACF$ has quantifier elimination (QE), hence every formula is $ACF$-equivalent to some formula in disjunctive normal form (and that every atomic formula is of the form $q(x)=0$ for some $q(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$), however I don't know how to continue from this point on to prove that $tp^{\underline{F}}(b/A)=tp^{\underline{F}}(d/h(A))$.
Can you guys help me here? I think I'm missing something quite obvious but nonetheless I can't see it. Also I stated only case 1 in full detail because I'm pretty confident that what I'm missing is what will get me through case 2 as well. Any help is very much appreciated :)
